# os.path.dirname(__file__) not displaying absolute path in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, operating-system

I just have a python file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
print os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

but when I execute it, the terminal displays a dot, instead of the absolute path to the script.

Comment: You should post the exact error message you're receiving. There are a lot of things that can cause this to fail- with the traceback, we can't be of much help.

Comment: There's no error message. The script just displays a point, and then I can work in terminal again

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps,

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
print os.path.realpath(__file__)
```

gives you what you're looking for?

Comment: Gives following error:.                                                                                   /test: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./test: line 4: `print os.path.realpath(__file__)'